# como configurar el connection-pool / pool de conexiones del componente camel-restlet

Tags: jboss

Pues eso, me da un error el servicio cuando hago muchas peticiones y tarda un poco en responder el endpoint, en mi ruta uso el componente restlet para hacer el llamado a un servicio y si por ejemplo hago 100 peticiones de 30 a 40 son respondidas pero las demás dan el error:

> "09:28:51,091 WARNING [org.restlet] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) An error
>   occurred during the communication with the remote HTTP server.:
>   org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting
>   for connection from pool"

En la documentación de camel solo veo pool de conexión del componente http4 no para restlet. No se si debo configurar el pool de las peticiones http en general..

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví al colocar ?socketTimeout=120000 <- milisegundos, como aparece en  http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

Dejo mi código como ejemplo:

`from("direct:goToApiEndpoint")
            .onCompletion()
                .modeBeforeConsumer()
                .process(new RestProcessor())
            .end()
            .to("restlet://localhost:8080/asociado/{asociado}?restletMethods=get&socketTimeout=120000");`